# How to use paranthesis in test built in command in Bash

Tags: bash

In the Bash Reference Manual, [chapter 4.1](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins), in the part about the *test* command:

> Expressions may be combined using the following operators, listed in decreasing order of precedence. The evaluation depends on the number of arguments; see below. Operator precedence is used when there are five or more arguments.
>
> ! expr
> True if expr is false.
>
> ( expr )
> Returns the value of expr. This may be used to override the normal precedence of operators.
> ...

Seems from this that one can do something like:

```
if [ 3 == 2 -a (2 == 2 -o 2 == 2) ];
```

The paranthesis () in this case will override the normal precedence (which is the -a first, in which case the whole expression will be true), but when I try to run this I get:

```
/test.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./test.sh: line 3: `if [ 3 == 2 -a (2 == 2 -o 2 == 2) ];'
```

Comment: See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html -- the `OB` markers indicate obsolescent functionality.

Comment: Parenthesis `(` and `)` would need to be quoted, because they have special meaning to bash, but they are not valid here anyway. You have by mistake looked up the command `[[` in the bash man page, but you are using `[` instead. (Look at _man test_ which describes the `[` command). Alternatively, use the `[[` command, which IMO is more convenient anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use of `-a`, `-o`, and parenthesis is marked as obsolescent in [the POSIX standard for `test`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html). If you *really* want to use them, though, you need to quote or escape the parens so they're passed to `[` (aka `test`) as arguments, rather than interpreted by the shell as syntax:

```
if [ 3 = 2 -a '(' 2 = 2 -o 2 = 2 ')' ]; then  # OBSOLETE SYNTAX, DO NOT USE
```

Note that if you put this code into http://shellcheck.net/, it will correctly throw warning [SC2166](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2166). Reading the wiki page describing that warning (linked above) is strongly recommended.

---

Avoiding obsolescent syntax, your line is correctly written as:

```
if [ 3 = 2 ] && { [ 2 = 2 ] || [ 2 = 2 ]; }; then
```

Note that string comparison is `=`, not `==`. There is no [POSIX-standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) `==` operator for `test`.

---

If you want bash-only extensions, use `[[` instead of `[`; that *does* let you reliably use parenthesis (and also makes `==` reliably available, though using `=` is better habit even then to develop finger memory compatible with POSIX-baseline shells):

```
if [[ 3 = 2 && ( 2 = 2 || 2 = 2 ) ]]; then
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually this text means that "!" just switch true and false.
It is not about parenthesis because test operator have no parenthesis in his syntax.

If you need several items to test, you should use just "-a"/"-o" options or separate test operators which you can combine in different groups you need:

```
if [ 3 == 2 ] && ( [ 2 == 2 -o 2 == 2 ] ); then
```

Comment: The test syntax does include parentheses, it's listed below the description of `!` (negation). But the syntax is clumsy (because it requires quoting/escaping, etc) and potentially ambiguous, so it's better not to use them within a `[ ]` test. (Note: using them *around* a `[ ]` test is ok, although using `{ ;}` instead avoids spawning a subshell.)